# Why are my raspberries' leaves turning brown?

Tags: diagnosis, raspberries

My yellow berries were doing great until a couple of months ago then the leaves started to turn brown and curl up. It started slowly but almost took over the whole plant. There is new growth on the stems and I did not find any caterpillars.

I live in USDA Zone 8a and we are in our monsoon season. We had maybe 12" of rain in the last 2 months. The plants are in half whiskey barrels.

Can you help me?

Comment: What variety of raspberry do you have? Can you post a photograph of the plant and leaves? Thanks, and welcome to the site.

Comment: Do you water the barrels? And yes, photo if possible please.

Comment: Fall gold and photo on the way,yes I water the barrels every couple of days have numerous drain holes

Comment: Can't seem to be able to down load photos on my kindle HELP!!!!!

Comment: @RichC What can we do?

Comment: I do hope if you are using barrels that you used STERILIZED POTTING SOIL and not garden soil and hopefully the barrels are raised off the ground.  No rock or gravel at the bottom of the pots.  What are you using for fertilizer?  Soil?  Drainage?  Definitely need photos...thanks!!

Comment: Hi Rich! Since we haven't been able to get some more information, such as people have asked for, this question's likely to be put on hold or closed. We still want to help, though, so if you [edit] the question within the next few days, it can possibly be re-opened. If you're still having trouble posting pictures, let us know. As @Stephie said, we can get you through that. If you've done something that has made your plant feel better, add that in so future visitors can learn from you! We hope to hear back from you!